# Displaying a Tile Map on Screen (HTML5/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My error console doesn't show any JavaScript errors. I've given my code a look-over and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. Nothing shows up on my screen, when there should be a tile map.

http://www.exeneva.com/html5/movingTankExample/

The goal is to eventually create an animated tank and have it move around the tile map. This is just a personal experiment to get better with working with tile maps and tile (cell-based) animation.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Line 21:

```
tileSheet.addEventListener('load', drawScreen(), false);  //wrong

tileSheet.addEventListener('load', drawScreen, false);    //right
```

Then you will see you have made another mistake:

```
Line 47: Uncaught ReferenceError: colrCtr is not defined
```

Change it to `colCtr`!

[image]

> Your cool game, now working.

Comment: spot on, just tested in jsfiddle

Comment: What would be the jQuery equivalent? I tried tileSheet.load(drawScreen()); but that didn't work.

Comment: @YangPulse - Remove the `()` when putting into any callback!

Comment: @YangPulse - Plus, if you think my answer is helpful, you can accept it as the solution. (click the checkmark)

Comment: I just tried tileSheet.load(drawScreen); but that didn't work.

Comment: @YangPulse - Have you changed `colrCtr` to `colCtr`?

Comment: Yes. I uploaded the version with tileSheet.load(drawScreen); to the link. colrCtr has been changed to colCtr

Comment: Oh I see. `new Image()` is not an jQuery object.

Comment: But new Image() is a JavaScript object, and that should work with jQuery, right?

Comment: You have to do it like this `var tileSheet = $("<img src='./img/tanks_sheet.png'>").load(drawScreen)[0];` (this is the jQuery way of doing things)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I've learned a lot! It's working now!

Comment: Nice! (Looking forward to see the final product~)